# How to return a view in another controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have a .net6 MVC application and I want the initial display startup page Index.cshtml not from inside the View\Home folder but from another directory AccountUpload\Index.cshtml. Also the controller is called AccountUploadController.

How can I do this from the program.cs?

Here's what I have in program.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMvc();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: I cannot understand your requirement? Can't you just place the `Index.cshtml` under `Views/AccountUpload/Index.cshtml` ? And then specify the path to it?

Comment: There is no Home folder or HomeController. What I have under Views is the AccoundUpload folder and inside it the Index.cshtml

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should be able to achieve your goal just by typing "AccountUpload" instead of "Home" in the MapControllerRoute method but I think you have already tried this (right?) so here are some other ways to do it:

1. In the Index action in your HomeController: redirect to the Index action in your AccountUploadController.
   Ex: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "AccountUpload");`
2. In the Index action in your HomeController: return the view Index.cshtml which is in the AccountUpload folder by specifying the file path.
   Ex: `return View("~/Views/AccountUpload/Index.cshtml");`

In both cases, you have to remember to pass the proper model to the view. By the way, the proper way is to specificy the inital action and controller in the Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

> I have a .net6 MVC application and I want the initial display startup
> page Index.cshtml not from inside the View\Home folder but from
> another directory AccountUpload\Index.cshtml. Also the controller is
> called AccountUploadController.

You could simply modify your pattern within [MapControllerRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route) which would call your AccountUpload page index while the application being initialized.

Scenario:

Let's have a look in action. Assuming your have following directory for your AccountUpload controller:

[image]

Conventional route in program.cs:

If you now want to call your Index.cshtml page from  AccountUpload controller by default you could modify your [conventional route defination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route) as following:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=AccountUpload}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [conventional route defination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)